# Interaction draw in projection

Tags: openlayers

I have a simple interaction on my map, by this interaction user can draw circle in any part of map. But i need to consider a current projection, can i apply projection to interaction? I try to say what if we draw circle on map center is looks like a circle, but if we draw it closed to poles - its looks like ellipse? May be somebody can help me.